# Python plot only part of data

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to plot any part or the data

here is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
... ...
xs = []
avg = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y1 = line.split(',')
            xs.append(float(x))
            avg.append(float(y1))
ax1.plot(xs, avg, label='avg')
```

I added some of the code so you can see the type of the variables

I tried :

```
ax1.plot(xs[avg>0], avg[avg>0], label='avg')
```

and didnt work

im matlab i would do some thing like :

```
Indxs=find (ys>0)
Plot(xs(indxs),ys(indxs))
```

Comment: You can look at numpy.where (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the indices of the subset you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct. The problem is that `xs` and `avg` are no numpy arrays. So you first need to convert those lists to numpy arrays, then the slicing will work as expected.

```
xs = np.array(xs)
avg = np.array(avg)
ax1.plot(xs[avg>0], avg[avg>0], label='avg')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you doesen't work since your index (avg > 0) in python is a boolean. When you are used to Matlab then you should definitely try numpy Boolean indexing.

you can do:

```
import numpy as np
xs = numpy.asarray(x)
ys = numpy.asarray(y)
ys_filtered = ys[x > 0]
```